# Exclude zero values but include NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want in my query to exclude only zero values but also keeping NULL.
I have tried a few options that work. It has a few 'JOIN' in it.
However.. They all seem to generate different results. The output have different amount of certain values.

E.g. lets say one option gives **COLUMN1** 10 rows with value 'A' and 5 rows of 'B' and 3 rows of 'C'. The other option gives me 7 rows of value 'A' and 9 rows of 'B' and 2 rows of 'C'. Which one should be most suitable (or neither?) and why:

where..

1. and a.exitreason<>'0' or a.exitreason is null
2. and (a.exitreason<>'0' or a.exitreason is null)
3. and ( isnull(a.exitreason,'') <>'0' OR  a.exitreason is null)

Or include it in my JOIN part of the query (table LocalOffice)?

Thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.PeriodDate,s.Number,SiteID,
s.LocalID,s.Appointment,s.Agreement,s.AgreementCode,a.ExitReason
FROM Office s
INNER JOIN Employer e ON s.PeriodDate=e.PeriodDate AND s.EmployerID=e.EmployerID
LEFT JOIN LocalOffice a ON a.LocalOfficeID=a.LocalOfficeID
WHERE.....
```

Comment: 2 looks correct to me - in (1) the order of calculation of AND and OR is not considered correctly

Answer (score 0):

The details you provided for your particular case aren't clear, but regarding the WHERE statements you've tried, they give different result sets as they rightly should (they're logically requesting different things).

Based on your initial description that you want all rows where given value is either 0 or NULL, your second condition will get you that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I want ALL values except 0, BUT NULLs as well